# A question about bilinear forms

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, bilinear-form

> Let $\phi$ be a bilinear form on a vector space $V$. Let $U$ be a vector subspace of $V$. Suppose that $\phi$ and $\phi_{|U\times U}$ are both non-degenerate. Prove that if $U$ is finite-dimensional, then $\phi_{|U^{\bot,L}\times U^{\bot,L}}$ is non-degenerate.

Here $U^{\bot,L} = \{ v\in V : \forall u\in U,\  \phi(v, u) = 0 \}$ and $U^{\bot,R} = \{ v\in V : \forall u\in U,\  \phi(u, v) = 0 \}$.

I know how to prove this if $V$ is finite dimensional but not sure when $V$ is infinite dimensional...

I can also prove that $ U^{\bot,L}\cap (U^{\bot,L})^{\bot,R} = \{0\}$, but for $U^{\bot,L}$ to be non degenerate we also need $U^{\bot,L}\cap (U^{\bot,L})^{\bot,L} = \{0\}$, and that seems far-fetched.

May I have some hint on this? Thank you.

Comment: Note that askers are expected to provide context for their questions, as is [explained here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). For example, it would be helpful if you could edit your question to include where you encountered this question, what your thoughts are on the question, and what you have tried so far.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Ok, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

$\boldsymbol{U^{\bot,L}\cap (U^{\bot,L})^{\bot,L} = \{0\}}$:

Since $\phi$ is non-degenerate, $V^{\bot,L}=\{0\}$.

$\Rightarrow$ $\forall u_k\in U^{\bot,L}-\{0\}$ $\exists v\in V$s.t. $\phi(u_k,v)\neq0$

Since $V = U \bigoplus U^{\bot,L}$, and $\forall u\in U,\ \phi(u_k, u)=0$, we must have $\exists v'\in U^{\bot,L},\ \phi(u_k,v')\neq0$.

$\boldsymbol{U^{\bot,L}\cap (U^{\bot,L})^{\bot,R} = \{0\}}$:

We also have $V = U \bigoplus U^{\bot,R}$.

Let $u_k\in U^{\bot,L}-\{0\}$, $\exists u \in U,\ u'\in U^{\bot,R}$, $u_k=u+u'$

$i.e. u_k - u = u'$

While $V^{\bot,R}=\{0\}\Rightarrow \exists v\in V,\ \phi(v,u_k-u)=\phi(v_1+v_2,u_k-u)\neq0$, for some $v_1\in U$, $v_2\in U^{\bot,L}$.

We have $\phi(v_1+v_2,u_k-u)=\phi(v_2,u_k-u)=\phi(v_2,u_k)\neq0$